# Custom Data View and inner datagrid resources issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatable

I am trying to customise the data column in a nested row in XAML but data view shows all the columns. I tried to add selective data grid text columns but the result is same it's showing all the data columns even I try to hide the columns but not succeeded.

2nd question: I am getting the data using stored procedure via data table but my inner data grid has a resource issue.

3rd need to bind data table with XAML code from cs file.

```
     <UserControl x:Class="mobilewpf.views.sale"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="500">
<Grid Background="#FF93BCBC" >
    <DataGrid x:Name="salegrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,201,10,10" Loaded="salegrid_load" LoadingRowDetails="salegrid1_loadingrowdetails" SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Invoice_id}" Header="ID" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Invoice_No}" Header="Invoice No" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Invoice_Date}" Header="Invoice Date" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding customer_Name}" Header="Customer Name" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding customer_Mobile}" Header="Customer Mobile" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <DataGrid x:Name="innerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataView}" 
                           CanUserAddRows="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Invoice_No}" Header="Invoice No" Width="100" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Invoice_Date}" Header="Invoice Date" Width="100" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding customer_Name}" Header="Customer Name" Width="100" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding customer_Mobile}" Header="Customer Mobile" Width="*" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Invoice_id}" Header="ID" Width="100" Visibility="Hidden"/>-->
                            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Invoice_id}" Header="ID" Width="100"/>-->
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Item_Name}" Header="Item Name" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Header="Quantity" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UnitPrice}" Header="Unit Price" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>                   
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate> 
     </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>


public partial class sale : UserControl
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    public sale()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.saledetaildata = ds.Tables["saledetaildata"].DefaultView;
    }

    public DataView saledetaildata { get; set;}

    private void salegrid_load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        salegriddata();
        //aaatest();
    }

    public void salegriddata()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IRFAN20170323\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=husnain;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("allsaleview", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("viewsale2", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("saleData");
        da.Fill(dt);
        salegrid1.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
        da1.Fill(ds, "saledetaildata");
        //salegrid1.ItemsSource =  ds.Tables["saleData"].DefaultView;
        //DataGrid grid = new DataGrid("gridOrderDetails");
        //innerGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["saledetaildata"].DefaultView;
        //return ds.Tables[].DefaultView;
    }

    public DataSet saleData { get; set; }

    private void salegrid1_loadingrowdetails(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid innerGrid = e.DetailsElement as DataGrid;

        if (innerGrid != null)
        {
        }
    }

    public void aaatest()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IRFAN20170323\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=husnain;Integrated Security=True");
        //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("viewsale", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("viewsale2", con);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da1.Fill(ds, "saledetaildata");
        innerGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["saledetaildata"].DefaultView;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are executing a stored procedure ("viewsale2") in the database that is determining the columns that are being returned.  So either make a new stored procedure of delete columns.  So best solution would be to make a copy of current datatable and then delete columns you do not want.

Comment: sorry, I think I could not properly explain my problem. i am getting the data throughout data table and connect the parent Datagrid with it like ("salegrid1.ItemsSource =  ds.Tables["saleData"].DefaultView;"). but when i try to connect inner grid with data view its giving all the columns i dont know how to get custom columns .like parent grid when i try to bind child or inner grid i facing the resouces issue .

Comment: So do you have to add new columns to the dataset?

Comment: i have two db tables from where i am feching the data table a is a invoice table and table b is a invoice detail table .invoice detail table rely on table a . parent grid i am binding with invoice table with code behind but for inner grid/child grid i could not able to bind with code behind but from the front side when i binding with dataview its giving table a complete result.                                                            (<DataGrid x:Name="innerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataView}" ) do you have any idea to bind inner grid with code behind or from front end any alternative way.

Comment: Are you getting an exception (said not able to bind)?  Does table b have the correct data?  You can put break point after b table is filled and hover over 'b'.  Then click on down arrow and select Data Visualizer.  I suspect you are binding but the view is not iin FRONT so you are not seeing the results.

Comment: table b is working perfectly i used the break point the show the result its perfect.i coould not bind inner grid with code behind its showing inner grid resource is not exist in current context

Comment: Does both DGVs exists?   Which one are you binding : <DataGrid x:Name="innerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataView}"

Comment: only parent grid exist  <DataGrid x:Name="salegrid1" > but inner grid not exist in current context